# How can I get the HTML attribute of an element from puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

How do I get an href attribute from an element in puppeteer?

I am trying to get the href attribute from the anchorTag.

```
const anchorTag = await page.$('table#middleContent_grvTransactionList > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(7) > a');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in many ways:

1. Using [`evaluate`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.0.0/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args):

```js
const href = await page.evaluate(el => el.getAttribute('href'), anchorTag);
```

2. Using [`getProperty`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.0.0/docs/api.md#elementhandlegetpropertypropertyname):

```js
const propertyHandle = await anchorTag.getProperty('href');
const href = await propertyHandle.jsonValue();
```

3. Using [`$eval`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.0.0/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1):

```js
const href = await page.$eval('table#middleContent_grvTransactionList > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(7) > a', el => el.getAttribute('href'));
```